# Set textview nil or empty in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I need to put empty, or nil, basically clean the textVIew to print the new value from a dictionary one textview in swift, how i can do this?
i have this code:

```
    for (chave, valor) in Dicionario
    {
        frase = frase + chave + "- Preço: " + String(stringInterpolationSegment: valor) + "\r\n"
    }
    if lista.text.isEmpty {
        lista.text = frase
    }else
    {
    ??
        lista.text = frase
    }
```

the code with ?? is what i need, because the list have the previous values

Comment: What do you mean with "clean it"? I understood the same thing as @newmediafreak . Please explain yourself if you need something different than that.

Comment: remove all value from a text view, put the text view empty to add the new values

Comment: @SaPires That's what my example does. Unless you've got some other code surrounding your example that does something weird with it. Can you show more of your code, since your example with my answer should work and somehow it doesn't.

Comment: i found the error, i always put the old values in the list :(